# How do you perform a sunspot search on a specific field in a has-many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Given using the following example as a base... and please correct me if this isn't set up correctly.

Migration Files:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name, null: false
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

User.create(first_name:'John', last_name:'Smith', email:'john@smith.com')  # id: 1
User.create(first_name:'Jane', last_name:'Smith', email:'jane@smith.com')  # id: 2

class CreateCustomAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :custom_attributes do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.text   :description, null: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

CustomAttribute.create(name:'is_married', description:'') # id: 1
CustomAttribute.create(name:'has_children', description:'')  # id: 2
CustomAttribute.create(name:'number_of_children', description:'')  # id: 3

class CreateUserCustomAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_custom_attributes do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false
      t.references :custom_attribute, null: false
      t.text       :value, null: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

# John
UserCustomAttribute.create(user_id: 1, custom_attribute_id: 1, value: 'no')
UserCustomAttribute.create(user_id: 1, custom_attribute_id: 2, value: 'yes')
UserCustomAttribute.create(user_id: 1, custom_attribute_id: 3, value: 4)

# Jane
UserCustomAttribute.create(user_id: 2, custom_attribute_id: 1, value: 'no')
UserCustomAttribute.create(user_id: 2, custom_attribute_id: 2, value: 'no')
UserCustomAttribute.create(user_id: 2, custom_attribute_id: 3, value: 0)
```

Models:

```
class CustomAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_custom_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_custom_attributes
end

class UserCustomAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :custom_attribute
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_custom_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :custom_attributes, through: :user_custom_attributes

  searchable do
    text :first_name, :last_name, :email
  end
end
```

I'm trying to allow "value" to be dynamic, whether it is a simple boolean (0,1), string ('speedy'), or serialized array of items ('---- Baseball- Football')

Is it possible to search for all users that have children (e.g. 'has_children' set to 'yes')?

For example: /users?fq[has_children]=yes

Also, would it possible to search for all users with children (e.g. 'number_of_children' is greater than 0)?

If so, how would you structure the 'searchable' block in the User model and the User.search block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want would be to start by separating out the different types of dynamic fields that you want (string, integer, boolean), maybe by adding an attribute_type: 'string', attribute_type: 'numerical', etc. Then you can use Sunspot's dynamic fields to search different types of dynamic data:

```
searchable do
  dynamic_string :string_attributes do
    user_custom_string_attributes.inject({}) do |hash, uca|
      hash.merge(uca.custom_attribute.name.to_sym => uca.value)
    end
  end

  dynamic_integer :numerical_attributes do
    user_custom_numerical_attributes.inject({}) do |hash, nuca|
      hash.merge(nuca.custom_attribute.name.to_sym => nuca.value.to_i) # just making sure it's an integer!
    end
  end
end

# Separate out the different types of attributes for different dynamic blocks
# via methods like the one below.

def user_custom_numerical_attributes
  user_custom_attributes.where(attribute_type: 'numerical')
end

def user_custom_string_attributes
  user_custom_attributes.where(attribute_type: 'string')
end
```

This will give you searchable 'string_attributes' objects that look like {:has_children => 'no'} or 'numerical_attributes' like {:number_of_children => 2}.

Then you can search with a block like so:

```
User.search do
  dynamic :string_attributes do
    with(:has_children, 'no')
  end

  dynamic :numerical_attributes do
    with(:number_of_children).greater_than(0)
  end
end
```

You can create dynamic fields for pretty much any data type except text; for that you'll have to use string instead. And once you've set up your dynamic fields, inside the `dynamic :field_name do` block you can use any of the non-text search methods demonstrated in the examples in the [Sunspot readme](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/README.md).